# ng build called twice consecutively without any changes should not perform operations

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am using Angular CLI 13.3.9 on Windows and created a new default application running `ng new SampleApp`.

When running `ng build` in the created SampleApp-folder the command takes around 15sec for the first run. Running the same command again, manually via entering `ng build` again, without any kind of changes it takes around 3sec. Any further runs will also take around 3sec.

Is there any way to configure `ng build` to run a change detection before it starts to bundle the application, copy assets and generating the Index html without any changes?
Expected behavior would be that it returns instantly with stating that nothing changed and output files are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature of angular after version 8 and it is called differential loading

The two build you are seeing is because of different browser targets.

You can find more information about that here

https://medium.com/@auth0/a-guide-to-angular-8s-differential-loading-ad08278a7d17

Comment: The second build is started manually by entering ```ng build``` one more time. I think that this is not related to differential loading.
I updated the question to make this clearer.

Comment: Is there anything specific you have change in your angular.json?

Comment: No, the angular.json file remained as is after it was created by the Angular CLI.
The behavior should be reproduceable.